# Prototype property throwing undefined

Tags: javascript, oop

why is the prototype `property` of the `instance` throwing `undefined`?.

```
function Test(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Test.prototype = {
    constructor: Test,
    sayHello : function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

var z = new Test("Hello");


console.log(z.prototype); //undefined
console.log(zUtils.constructor); // Test
```

I am able to access the sayHello method via `z.sayHello(`), then why is my `instance` `prototype` returning me undefined instead of `Test.prototype`?.

Comment: Because you can't get prototype of the object like this, there is no such property, because prototype is not exposed as a property. You can get it using `Object.getPrototypeOf` method. For example: `Object.getPrototypeOf(z) === Test.prototype`.

Comment: @dfsq You shouldn't answer in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of confusion is that the word `prototype` kind of has two meanings.

**1. Function property**. Any function can have a `prototype` property, which is an object. In your case

```
Test.prototype = {
    sayHello: function() {}
}
```

Properties of this object become inherited properties and methods of the objects constructed with this constructor function:

```
var z = new Test();
```

Now `z` has a method property `sayHello`, which you configured with the help of the `Test.prototype` object.

**2. Instance prototype**. The instance object, in your case `z`, has *internal* reference to the prototype object from point #1 above. This reference is used internally to resolve properties and methods in the prototype chain. However this reference *is not* supposed to be accessible directly, and you can't access this reference with `prototype` property of the instance.

In chrome and Firefox you can use [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property, but its usage is deprecated.

To get a prototype which was used during object construction you should use `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(z) === Test.prototype; // true
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get prototype, use `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. So, in your example, try with `Object.getPrototypeOf(z)`

Answer (score 0):

you should be using `getPrototypeOf` method on the object.like this:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(z);
```

you can do like this:

```
Test.prototype=Object.getPrototypeOf(z);
    console.log(Test.prototype);
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(z));
```